# How to do a loop scrape from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, screen-scraping

So, I have a data frame with a lot of URL, but there is only the second part of the link... I want to do a loop-scrape of every URL but I don't know how to do. I already know what I want to scrape, but I don't know how do the loop.

This is the main: https://www.brewersfriend.com

And the second part is in the row of data frame['URL']

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbTrC.png)

I try so:

```js
base = 'https://www.brewersfriend.com'
links = [base + df['URL'] for r in df['URL']]
```

But it doesn't work, because doesn't take every row...

Someone can help me?

Comment: it should be... links = [base + r for r in df['URL']]

Comment: `links = [f'{base}{r}' for r in df['URL']]`

Answer (score 0):

```
df['links'] = df['URL'].apply(lambda x : 'https://www.brewersfriend.com' + x )
```